Use OpenCV in qt qmake project: undefined reference
I want to use OpenCV in a QT qmake project. The vrsions are opencv 4.9.0 and QT 5.15.2(MSV 2019,64bit).
.pro file
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include
LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib \
        -lopencv_world490

mainwindow.cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv; 

...
cv::Mat mat; 
...


After build, I get the error:
undefined reference to cv::Mat::Mat()
Hint: my project is a widget program with qmake (not cmake).

what can you learn about "undefined reference" errors?

I think it is related to linking files and libraries. I tried any type of linking that is available in the net, and of course the types and functions load in auto complete, but after building project the error arised!

is there actually an opencv_world490 file in that directory? does Qt actually use the Microsoft MSVC compiler? or does it use mingw?

Since you are using msvc binaries are you compiling with msvc and not MinGW? These will not work with MinGW / g++.

@ChristophRackwitz , yes the file exists in the directory. In the "about" menu of QT is written "Based on QT5.15.2 (MSVC 2019,64bit).

@drescherjm, actually I tried both with different versions, but the result is same.

what can you see in the directory C:/opencv/build/include?

@ChristophRackwitz , A folder named "opencv2"

alright, that's as it should be. what do you see in C:/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib? I -- checked that vc16 corresponds to Visual Studio 2019. that's ok too.

My problem finally resolved with the following actions:

I used 'OpenCV 4.5.2' (downloded from https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build) .

In the .cpp file replaced
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
By
'''#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>'''

Copy .dll files (in the bin folder of opencv) to my project debug/release folder.


Hope this helps others too.

Step 2 is pointless, the only thing opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp does is include opencv2/highgui.hpp.

You also said that you're using Visual C++, not MingW, so I really don't get what step number 1 is useful for. Please, clarify that in your question, as is, this answer is quite misleading.
